# Close bottom sheet on pressing back button on android

Tags: react-native, expo, bottom-sheet

I am using @gorhom/bottom-sheet library in react native expo and I would like to close the sheet when I press the back button on android, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a backHandler event in your useEffect and call the bottomSheetRef.current.close() method inside it:-

```
useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
     bottomSheetRef.current.close()
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

react native elements bottom sheet close on back button press

```
  const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ["%100", "20%"], []);
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState<boolean>(false);

useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        if (isShowing) {
          sheetRef.current?.close();
          return true;
        } else if (!isShowing) {
          navigation.goBack();
          return true;
        }
      };
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);
      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);
    }, [sheetRef, isShowing])
  );



     

  <BottomSheet
    ref={sheetRef}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    enablePanDownToClose={true}
    onChange={(idx) => {
    setIsShowing(idx < 1 ? false : true);
    }}
    backdropComponent={BottomSheetBackdrop}
    >
      <BottomSheetView>
        <Text>Awesome </Text>
      </BottomSheetView>
   </BottomSheet>
```